# log method calls per object

Tags: python, logging, organization, python-3.x

How to log method calls on a per object basis for a particular class?
I.e. after instanciating `a = myClass()` I somehow want to keep a log for what methods have been called on `a` like

```
a.reverse()
a.loadNewData()
a.substract(somenparray)
```

later I want be able to look at this object's history/log e.g. `a.log()`.
All logging stuff I've seen so far could be used to log all function calls but not restricted to a per object basis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, which increments a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) every time a [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) attribute is accessed:

```
class LoggingMixIn:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log = Counter()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(attr):
            self._log[name] += 1
        return attr

    def log(self):
        return self._log
```

In use:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> class Demo(LoggingMixIn):
        def method1(self):
            pass
        def method2(self):
            pass


>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.method1()
>>> d.method2()
>>> d.method2()
>>> d.log()
Counter({'method2': 2, 'method1': 1, 'log': 1})
```

You can special-case `name == 'log'` if you don't want to log calls to `log`. However, note that this *won't* log calls to the instance itself, or to a property:

```
>>> class Demo(LoggingMixIn):
    def method(self):
        pass
    @property
    def property(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self):
        pass


>>> d = Demo()
>>> d.method()
>>> d.property
>>> d()
>>> d.log()
Counter({'log': 1, 'method': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks! It is not completely what I wanted, but I should be able to go from there: I wanted to log the calls per object in chronological order, such that I afterwards can tell: on this object first X was called, then Y before Z was called two times.